# Is there a way to access distant relations in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have four tables and somehow in my Payrolls table, I want to select an employee and fill out the details of his/her payroll. The only problem is that I can't get the employee position details because it is not connected directly to Payrolls table.

[image]

**Employees Model**

```
class Employees extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'gender',
    'address',
    'positions_id'
];

public function positions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Positions::class);
}

public function payrolls()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Payrolls::class);
}
}
```

**Positions Model**

```
class Positions extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'basic_pay'
];

public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Employees::class);
}
}
```

**Payrolls Model**

```
class Payrolls extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'days_work',
    'overtime_hrs',
    'late',
    'absences',
    'bonuses',
    'employees_id'
];

public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employees::class);
}
}
```

Is there a way where I can connect Payrolls and Positions? I want to get the basic_pay from the Positions table and display it on the Payrolls table (maybe through an Intermediate table).

Comment: What have you tried so far? The Employee model has a `position_id`, so what's the problem in getting the referenced entity?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have done showing a single payroll and somehow I can only get the `positions_id` in the Payroll blade like this:

`{{ $payrolls->employees->pluck('positions_id')->first() }}`

What I want is to pluck the `basic_pay` column in the show.blade Payroll so I can do computation which is impossible and I only get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out.**

I used query builder to join the three tables(employees, payrolls, positions) on the Controller:

```
public function show(Employees $employee, Payrolls $payroll)
{
    $basic_pay = DB::table('payrolls')
    ->join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'payrolls.employees_id')
    ->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'employees.positions_id')
    ->select('positions.basic_pay')
    ->where('payrolls.employees_id', '=', $payroll->employees_id)
    ->get();

    $position_name = DB::table('payrolls')
    ->join('employees', 'employees.id', '=', 'payrolls.employees_id')
    ->join('positions', 'positions.id', '=', 'employees.positions_id')
    ->select('positions.name')
    ->where('payrolls.employees_id', '=', $payroll->employees_id)
    ->get();

    return view('payrolls.show')
    ->with('payrolls', $payroll)
    ->with('basic_pay', $basic_pay)
    ->with('position_name', $position_name)
    ->with('employees', $employee);
}
```

And on my views:

```
<label><h4>Position: </h4></label>
<span style="font-size: 25px">
   {{ $position_name->pluck('name')->first() }}
</span><br>

<label><h4>Basic Pay: </h4></label>
<span style="font-size: 25px">
   {{ $basic_pay->pluck('basic_pay')->first() }}
</span><br>
```

I used pluck to pluck the desired column field that I want to show.